# How to know the version of some package to be installed by apt-get in advance?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, debian, apt, xenomai

How to know the version of some package to be installed by apt-get in advance?

I see, I could make it by using apt-cache madison.
But i does not work well all the time, for example, xenomai package.
For details, see below.

```
##sucessfully
ubuntu:~$ apt-cache madison libcurl3
      libcurl3 | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
      libcurl3 | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.14 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
      libcurl3 | 7.47.0-1ubuntu2 | http://mirrors.aliyun.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
    ubuntu:~$

##failed
ubuntu:~$ apt-cache madison xenomai
ubuntu:~$ #no output indeed!
```

Comment: `apt-cache policy libcurl3`

Comment: Yea,you are right.It works.

Answer (score 0):

this is manly because "madison" is a debian tool and not a ubuntu tool.
Please always use madison on https://qa.debian.org/madison.php

Your example xenomai is visible here
https://qa.debian.org/madison.php?package=xenomai&table=ubuntu

[image]

Comment: You mean that i should not use `apt-cache madison` in ubuntu and use madison on https://qa.debian.org/madison.php instead.Am i right?